# How to use ratio test for the series $\frac{n}{2^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

given this series:

$$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{2^2}...\frac{n}{2^n}$$

How to test for convergence or divergence through the ratio test?

I rearranged it likeso:

$$\frac{n^2}{2^n+1}$$

To show that the series diverges.

However, how do I show that:

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=l$$

where $l$ < 1 = convergence, and $l$ > 1 = divergence.

How do I get it into the fractional form $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$?

Comment: We have $a_n=\dfrac{n}{2^{n}}$. This gives us $a_{n+1}=\dfrac{n+1}{2^{n+1}}$. It is evident that $\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\dfrac{n+1}{2^{n+1}}\cdot \dfrac{2^n}{n}=\dfrac{n+1}{2n}$. Now $n+1\leq 2n\forall\ n\in \mathbb N$, which means that $l<1$, so the series is actually convergent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We know that
$$a_n :=\frac{n}{2^n}, \quad a_{n+1} = \frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}}.$$
Now we have to calculate
$$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\cfrac{\frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}}}{\frac{n}{2^n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)2^n}{n2^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+1}{n}.$$
This limit converges to $1$. That means that $L=1/2$. Since $L<1$, the sequence converges absolutely.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{\frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}}}{\frac{n}{2^n}} = \frac12\frac{n+1}{n}$$

which is between $\frac12$ and $\frac34$ when $n\ge 2$ so it converges.

In fact the sum is $2-\dfrac{n+2}{2^n}$ and so it converges to $2$

Answer (score 1):

$a_n=\dfrac n{2^n}\implies \dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\dfrac{\dfrac{n+1}{2^{n+1}}}{\dfrac n{2^n}}=\dfrac{n+1}{2n}\to\dfrac12$.